# 06-16 12:05:46.802: E/chromium(15693): [ERROR:audio_manager_android.cc(239)] Unable to select audio device

Tags: android, audio, video, webrtc, chromium

I am building an video/audio calling app in android using xwalkview. I am receiving this error 90% times not every time while making audio/video call and because of this I am not receiving video on either side. I have added permissions of Record_Audio,camera,Modify_audio_settings .

log.txt

```
 06-16 12:00:51.953: W/AudioManagerAndroid(12936): Requires MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS and RECORD_AUDIO
 06-16 12:00:51.953: W/AudioManagerAndroid(12936): No audio device will be available for recording
 06-16 12:00:51.986: W/AudioManagerAndroid(12936): Requires MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS and RECORD_AUDIO
 06-16 12:00:51.986: W/AudioManagerAndroid(12936): Selected device will not be available for recording
 06-16 12:00:51.986: E/chromium(12936): [ERROR:audio_manager_android.cc(239)] Unable to select audio device!
```

Comment: maybe you have android 6?

Comment: No I am working on lollipop

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917751/webview-webrtc-not-working

Answer (score 0):

its problems for reload the webview after accepting the permission , after too much research , found this code and copy the below code and 100% working and I hope your problem resolve :-

```
mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                myRequest = request;
                for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
                    if (permission.equals("android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE")) {
                        demandForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                    } else {
                        myRequest.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest request) {
            super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request);
        }
```

more code in this link **[Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528122/allowed-camera-audio-or-all-other-permissions-on-webview-webrtc-chromium-web)**