# WebRTC error inside Chromium WebView: "CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported"

Tags: android, android-webview, webrtc, android-permissions, webviewchromium

I'm trying to show `WebRTC` chat in `WebView`.
According to [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview), `WebView v36` supports `WebRTC`. For my test I'm using a device with `Chrome/39.0.0.0` and I have added permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

but when I enter into the chat, I see a Chromium error log *(device doesn't show \ translate anything, only 'loading' progress bar)*:

```
W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS and RECORD_AUDIO
W/AudioManagerAndroid: No audio device will be available for recording
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(178)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(178)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS and RECORD_AUDIO
W/AudioManagerAndroid: No audio device will be available for recording
D/ChromiumCameraInfo: Camera enumerated: front
```

Tested on a real device, Android 5.1.1.

Comment: What is your target sdk version? If you set 23 or above, you must request these as runtime permissions.

Comment: @Simon Marquis, yep. thanks. i've missed it

Comment: hm, added `request.grant(request.getResources());` - video is ok - audio issue still remains `WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.`

Comment: Try to set targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: tried sdk 22 - dosen't help  :(

Comment: Your error is in the permissions declaration in the Manifest. It should be "uses-permission" instead of "user-permission" for MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS. Good look!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

additional request for permissions is needed

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });
```

*update* but it not working for audio capture

**UPDATE** found working google-sample code [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/webrtc-example)

Comment: Any suggestion for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180093/cant-access-camera-from-android-webview-chrome-frame-in-context-of-webrtc

Comment: @NikolaLukic hi, have you tried https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/blob/master/webrtc-example/app/src/main/java/com/google/chrome/android/webrtcsample/MainActivity.java this sample?

Comment: Yes this project works but i still wanna know what is the problem with my project . Diff is only that i not use drawer layout and fragment layout ?!? thanks

Comment: Hello @JonathanDunlap audio capture works in google-sample that i've shared in the answer

Comment: So where exactly do you add that code above, as in what file?

Comment: Hello @JohnnyGasyna, as i remember i've just replace my code with provided in sample. I'm not working on this project now and not able to check :(

Comment: @NikolaLukic: can you please tell me how did you solve ? I tried same in my project, but it's not working.

Comment: I have these permissions, but still getting error ```WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.```

Comment: where i can add this code, i am using flutter.

Comment: @Binnikumari this code is for native android. so, if you have your own implementation you need to add it to android native related code. If you are using library from pub check documentation or create an issue

Answer (score 10):

You need these permissions to access Camera and Microphone

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

// don't miss this one
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Next you need to grant permissions to your webview, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest) for more details:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                            PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE,
                            PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
                    };
                    request.grant(PERMISSIONS);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

If audio playback is not working, use this:

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Comment: please share the issue you are having

Comment: If the app has the permissions, the webview won't ask any other permissions?

Comment: app permissions are not going to be enough, you need to grant permissions for webview as well, check the code above where webchromeclient is granted permissions `webview.setWebChromeClient(..){onPermissionRequest()}`

Comment: Yes, So, if you implement that part, it passes app's permissions to the webview. And the user doesn't need to be asked twice about the same permissions. Am I right?

Comment: yes user should not be asked again if app permissions are granted already

Comment: I have these permissions, but still getting error ```WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.```

Comment: @Muhammad Shuja you are the men!! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where exactly should I add the Java code?

Comment: where I can add this code?? I am trying in flutter.

Answer (score 2):

My experience with this in 2022:

1. CAMERA and RECORD_AUDIO permissions need to be declared in Manifest
2. `setWebChromeClient.onPermissionRequest` should check if those permissions have already been granted. If not, use `registerForActivityResult(new RequestMultiplePermissions())` to ask the user to grant them.

Answer (score 1):

its mostly error in webview reload becuase when we will request for audio , camera permission on webview , after accept permission , we need to refresh the webpage.

```
   if (permission.equals("android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE")) {
                        demandForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                    } else {
                        myRequest.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
```

I also stuck this problem for many days but after in below link code ,  100% working code **[Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528122/allowed-camera-audio-or-all-other-permissions-on-webview-webrtc-chromium-web)**

Comment: Can you update the link? Page not found.