# Can't access camera from Android webView (chrome frame) in context of webRTC

Tags: google-chrome, android-webview, webrtc

App is based on webRTC vs websocket . 
Android studio 2.3.2 last version.

I already use:

https protocol , autoplay ,  android version 7.0 (min > android 5.0) .
 ***App works on all supported browsers only android webview generate error***.

This is first lines of errors log in **logcat** (android studio last ver):

> E/chromium: [ERROR:audio_manager_android.cc(264)] Unable to select audio device! E/cr_VideoCapture: allocate: manager.openCamera: 
>                                                                                            SecurityException: validateConnectLocked:1112: Caller
>   "com.testwebrtc.nikola.myapplication" cannot
>   open camera "1" without camera permission
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:628)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:347)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:450)
>                                                                                                 at
>   org.chromium.media.VideoCaptureCamera2.startCapture(VideoCaptureCamera2.java:661)

Other variant for error:

> [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(199)]
>   WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.

***This is error log from chrome/webview*** (from errorCallBack - getUserMedia ):

```
      An error occcurred [CODE NotAllowedError]

      other error variant: 

      trackstarterror
```

**Android Code** looks like:

```
package com.project.TEST.xxx;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1) )
                .commit();

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        private WebView mWebRTCWebView;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            mWebRTCWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);

            setUpWebViewDefaults(mWebRTCWebView);

            mWebRTCWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");

            mWebRTCWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            request.grant(request.getResources());

                        }
                    });
                }

            });

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            /**
             * When the application falls into the background we want to stop the media stream
             * such that the camera is free to use by other apps.
             */
            mWebRTCWebView.evaluateJavascript("if(window.localStream){window.localStream.stop();}", null);
        }

        /*
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
*/

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);

            Activity a;

            if (context instanceof Activity){
                a=(Activity) context;

            }

        }

        /**
         * Convenience method to set some generic defaults for a
         * given WebView
         *
         * @param webView
         */
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
            WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

            // Enable Javascript
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

            // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            // Allow use of Local Storage
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
                settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            }

            // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
            }

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            // AppRTC requires third party cookies to work
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebRTCWebView, true);
        }
    }


}
```

Build.gradle-project :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle - module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.test.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Android  Manifest.xml :

```
....
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.level.full" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.capability.raw" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />

...
```

Comment: could you share the whole code related to `webView`? for instance in provided below can't find `setWebViewClient` call

Comment: I make copy , looks same... Something about target and other version setting , i am still pionir for android platform....

Comment: @user5599807  My best score for now : I got remote stream on webview , also getusermedia pass success . No local video preview still black screen....

Comment: hi, sorry i was overloaded last time. have you deal with id?

Comment: Hi. Just went into this today. Did you find a solution? :) thanks

Comment: Actually no , i use copy project from google ...

Comment: I works on other projects , in new android api we need to check security and implement handle listener for that request. Alert message with "allow" button. I must check this if i miss something about api versions...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grant permissions in this way:

```
yourWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Excellent answer, this saves lot of work, Thanks :) @Amos

Comment: Because time ticking i will ascept this answer. It's posible to be right answer. In one moment (maybe 7.0) permisions was strict definition ( you need to use grant call for user request).

Comment: From a documentation point of view, this is wrong.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest To avoid unintentionally granting requests for new permissions, you should pass the specific permissions you intend to grant to grant(), and avoid writing code like this example:

 permissionRequest.grant(permissionRequest.getResources())  // This is wrong!!!

Comment: You can grant ressources for your expected domain only. By example : 
if (request.origin.toString() == "https://$httpServerDomain/") {
   request.grant(request.resources)
} else {
    request.deny()
}

Comment: This will help - @Dmitrijs mentioned you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61609282/9427138) method as per the documentation

Answer (score 5):

The `WebView` requests permission from the App, but the App is not granted these permissions from the user.

You should invoke App's permission request to the user, as mentioned in [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Now I found that the permissions WebRTC requires is those:

```
onPermissionRequest: android.webkit.resource.VIDEO_CAPTURE
onPermissionRequest: android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When providing an answer, it is better to fully explain your solution, providing an example if possible. Linking to documentation is nice if used as a reference to backup your answer, but is not sufficient on its own.

Comment: I will try it , it is very possible

Answer (score 3):

Your app need request permission before use camera

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i already done this for camera , camera2 , microphone etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need these permissions to access Camera and Microphone

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

// don't miss this one
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Next you need to grant permissions to your webview, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest) for more details:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                            PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE,
                            PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
                    };
                    request.grant(PERMISSIONS);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

If audio playback is not working, use this:

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

its problems for reload the webview , after too much research , found this code and create this below code :-

```
 mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            myRequest = request;
            for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
                if (permission.equals("android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE")) {
                    demandForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                } else {
                    myRequest.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest request) {
        super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request);
    }
```

more info in this page **[Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528122/allowed-camera-audio-or-all-other-permissions-on-webview-webrtc-chromium-web)**

Comment: Always is good to get more android devices in working regime. thks for LOLLIPOP check. And welcome to the community!